# How to solve error in passing the value to javascript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function

```
function del(str)
{
    alert(str);
}
```

and i have some ahref links for passing value in above javascript function like these

```
 1. <a href="javascript: del(13121110581541114);">Click</a>


 2. <a href="javascript: del(13121110581541118);">Click</a>


 3. <a href="javascript: del(13121110581541039);">Click</a>


 4. <a href="javascript: del(13121110581541117);">Click</a>
```

But problem if i click on link which have Even number for passing then alert show right digit, but when i click on link which have Odd number for passing then alert show (passing number + 1) digit

**for E.g on click 1st ahref alert show 13121110581541114**

**while on click 3rd ahref alert show 13121110581541040**

i don't know what's problem, plz help me

Comment: you can try `del('13121110581541039')` for the numbers

Comment: If you are expectin str than enclose your numbers in single quotes. Not sure why is it happening :/  http://jsbin.com/aTofIKex/1/edit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This number can't be represented in the JavaScript number format (which is the [IEEE754 double format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision_floating-point_format)) : `13121110581541039`

You need to change the design of your application : use strings for example, or make it so you deal only with integers whose absolute value is smaller than `2^53`.

Comment: can i use this for passing f5d3fb029a2379bbae54abb7883e2135

Comment: @user3100198 I don't get the question in your comment. Is that a string ?

Comment: You can pass any string.